# Something wrong with django

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to learn django and i faced problem.

`Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']`

I searched same issue's but solutions didn't work for me.
Maybe it's important -  i follow by this tutorial 
http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/extend_your_application/index.html
Thank you!

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Django Girls blog</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
            <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
        </head>
        <body>

                <div class="page-header">
                       <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="content container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            {% block content %}
                            {% endblock %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

traceback error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.8.1
Python Version: 3.4.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Template error:
In template D:\Projects\mysite\blog\templates\blog\base.html, error at line 13
   Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

   3 :         <head>



   4 :             <title>Django Girls blog</title>



   5 :             <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">



   6 :             <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">



   7 :             <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>



   8 :             <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">



   9 :         </head>



   10 :         <body>



   11 : 



   12 :                 <div class="page-header">



   13 :                        <h1><a href=" {% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %} ">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>



   14 :                 </div>



   15 :                 <div class="content container">



   16 :                     <div class="row">



   17 :                         <div class="col-md-8">



   18 :                             {% block content %}



   19 :                             {% endblock %}



   20 :                         </div>



   21 :                     </div>



   22 :                 </div>



   23 : 


Traceback:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\Projects\mysite\blog\views.py" in post_list
  8.     return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  99.         return template.render(context, request)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  74.         return self.template.render(context)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  209.                     return self._render(context)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  135.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  507.                         six.reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py" in reraise
  659.         raise value
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  493.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  579.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  496.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback for your error?

Comment: Your `post.pk` is empty, are you using the default Django's model PK ?

Comment: Joey Wilhelm - i added it.

Comment: @Gocht i think yes...

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title for your question. Apart from anything else, the problem is with your code, not Django.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ok, thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're trying to access to a single `post` without iterating over `posts`.

As you can see in your `post_list` view, you have:

```
...
return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

So, you send a variable named `posts` to your template.

But in your template you try to access to `post`:

```
<h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
```

But it doesn't exists.

You should iterate over `posts`, example:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
{% endfor %}
```

That should work.

Comment: @J.Galt good for your, if this answer help please consider accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with:

```
{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}
```

at that scope in your `base.html` template, there is no `post` variable hence `post.pk` resolves to empty string. So then Django tries to do url reverse with empty `pk` which fails.

In order for `{% url %}` to work, you will need to add post in there.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you missed a piece in the tutorial, here: http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/extend_your_application/index.html#create-a-template-link-to-a-posts-detail

In that step, it is instructing you to create a new template, and the line creating your problem, `<h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>`, would be added to that template.

That line in particular will not work in your base.html, as there is no variable named `post`. That variable is created as part of a loop in the new template in that step of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Just replace for this:

```
return redirect('blog.views.post_detail', pk=post.pk)
```